# htaccess 307 redirect, This file should be served over HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect a folder to another by htaccess file. That's working, but I'm loosing the https and got the error "the file was redirected through an insecure connection. This file should be served over HTTPS.".
This is my code :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]
  RewriteRule ^old_folder/(.*)$ /new_folder/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I also saw in network browser a 307 redirection even if I'm trying to have a 301 redirection.
Could anyone help me ?

Comment: Are there any other directives in your htaccess file or are there any other htaccess files in subdirectories? There’s nothing in what you’ve posted that would cause this or trigger a 307 for that matter.

Comment: No, nothing specific. Is there anyway to force the https ?

Comment: “I’m loosing the https” - By the sounds of it you already have an _erroneous_ redirect (or request) from https to http (somewhere), so you need to resolve that before attempting to redirect back from http to https, otherwise you will likely get a redirect loop!?

Comment: What do you mean by “nothing specific”? Unless you have other directives in your config file then the first two rules you have posted are probably redundant. (?)

Comment: Another thought... “I’m loosing the https” - are you actually “losing” the https, or was it never present to begin with? The directive you posted does nothing with the protocol, it is preserved. So if it was never present on the initial request then it’s not going to be present on the redirect response either, but nothing is “lost”. (?)